# Get, treat and set data from a spreadsheet to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm new to GAS. I'm trying to accomplish four tasks in a single spreadsheet with three separate sheets to relate to.

1. I want to copy data from the 'rawData sheet', set it in an array, rearrange the array, and set the values in the 'destination sheet'. And keep it active for new submissions (i.e. getLastRow/appendRow).
2. In 'destination sheet' I want to color code based on status.
3. Create a button in 'destination sheet' to mark row(case) complete and move from 'destination' to the 'complete sheet'.
4. And add onEdit triggers for each.

Your input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
 function colorCode() {

  var range = outerArray;
  Logger.log(range);

  var row = dBoard.getRange(dBoard.getLastRow(),1,1,dBoard.getLastColumn());

  var submitter = range[3];
  var status = range[11];
   Logger.log(submitter);
   Logger.log(status);

  //var column = range.getColumn();
  //var row = range.getRow();


  if (status === "Approved"){
    var rowToColor = row.offset(0,0,1,13);
    rowToColor.setBackground("#6bb2ff");     
  }

  else if (status === "Requester"){
    var rowToColor = row.offset(0,0,1,13);
    rowToColor.setBackground("#ffe16b"); 
  }

  else if (range === 12 && range > 1 && status === "Denied"){
    var rowToColor = row.offset(0,0,1,13);
    rowToColor.setBackground("#f9441b"); 
  }
}

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source1 = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of rawData");
var dBoard = ss.getSheetByName("dBoard2");

//function copyData() {
  //var rawD = source1.getRange(1,1,source1.getLastRow(),source1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  //Logger.log(rawD);

function setData() {

  var rawD = source1.getRange(source1.getLastRow(),1,1,source1.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  //Logger.log(limits);

  var columnA = rawD[0][0];
  var columnB = rawD[0][18];
  var columnC = rawD[0][13];
  var columnD = rawD[0][2];
  var columnE = rawD[0][3]
  var columnF = rawD[0][4];
  var columnG = rawD[0][5];
  var columnH = rawD[0][6];
  var columnI = rawD[0][7];
  var columnJ = rawD[0][8];
  var columnK = rawD[0][9];
  var columnL = rawD[0][11];
  var columnM = rawD[0][12];

  var outerArray = [columnA,
                    columnB,
                    columnC,
                    columnD,
                    columnE,
                    columnF,
                    columnG,
                    columnH,
                    columnI,
                    columnJ,
                    columnK,
                    columnL,
                    columnM];

  Logger.log(columnA);
  Logger.log(columnB);
  Logger.log(outerArray);

  dBoard.getRange(2,1,outerArray.length,outerArray.length);
  dBoard.appendRow(outerArray);
}
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome ! You say "I'm trying to accomplish", but gave nothing to us. What did you tried for know ? What did you find on internet and why it wasn't helping ? Can you do a part of your question without our help ?

Comment: @NatNgs here's what I got so far. Sorry about that. I broke the first commandment of the site. My first question.

Comment: What's outerArray? It looks undefined to me.  Where is dBoard defined?